# MVC Controller not return JSON List

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I have this code in Controller:

```
  public JsonResult getSmetkiList()
  {
      List<smetki> smetkiLST = new List<smetki>();
      using (leskaEntities dc = new leskaEntities())
      {
          smetkiLST = dc.smetkis.OrderBy(a => a.smID).ToList();
      }
      return new JsonResult { Data = smetkiLST, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
  }
```

if i try to access list i get server error 500 Network Debugging, and in the browser i have this error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ObjectDisposedException: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Here is smetki class:

```
  public int smID { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Dobavuvac")]
        public int firmaID { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}"), DisplayName("Datum")]
        public DateTime datumSM { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Beleska")]
        public string noteSM { get; set; }


        public virtual firmi firmi { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<trosoci> trosocis { get; set; }

        public List<trosoci> trosociL { get; set; }

        public decimal NetTotalTR
        {
            get
            {
                if (trosocis == null)
                {
                    return decimal.Zero;
                }
                return trosocis.Sum((trosoci i) => i.vkupnot);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you share your `smetki` class?

Comment: @ MaKCbIMKo you can see in update of question.

Comment: Your model contains properties which are currently lazy-loaded (`virtual ICollection<trosoci>`) etc. You need to eager-load load them (e.g. using `.Include()` before the context is disposed)

Comment: @Xelmep - i've put the answer (see below).

Answer (score 0):

Now I see your `smetki` class and I can say that the problem is that you're trying to return the collections of `smetki`.

`smetki` class has a reference collections (like `ICollection<trosoci> trosocis`). It's a virtual collections that require the open connection in order to iterate.

Therefore, when your `using` is finished and you try to serialize to json these reference collections it still looking for db connection which was closed (disposed).

The solution is pretty simple: you just need to convert (Map) `smetki` class in something without linked collections (it's might be called view model class).  And, if you need to serialize all linked entities/collections, then you need to create a view models for these classes as well.

Hope that will help.

If you still have any questions - feel free to ask.

Comment: I need also data from collection, can you see my answer (Above), with that code work property, can you help me to re-build the code and get back like a previous?

Comment: There is only different in `leskaEntities.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;`. Try to add this (it should help). However, it's not the best solution, IMHO.

Comment: Yes, This is correct and usable, Thank you to you and everyone other. :). I updated answer with correct code.

Comment: You're welcome :) Was glad to help. Feel free to ask the questions (if any).

Answer (score 0):

Because i had Deleted Controllers, now i Decompiled from hosted project, and with decompiling i have this code:

```
public JsonResult getSmetkiList()
        {
            List<smetki> data = new List<smetki>();
            using (leskaEntities leskaEntities = new leskaEntities())
            {
                leskaEntities.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
                data = (from a in leskaEntities.smetkis
                orderby a.smID
                select a).ToList<smetki>();
            }
            return new JsonResult
            {
                Data = data,
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            };
        }
```

With this code work property JSON Result List.

When i try to re-write like a code in question i have that error.

Here is the correct code:

```
public JsonResult getSmetkiList()
{
    List<smetki> datasm = new List<smetki>();
    using (leskaEntities dc = new leskaEntities())
    {
       dc.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
       datasm = dc.smetkis.OrderBy(a => a.smID).ToList();
    }
    return new JsonResult { Data = datasm, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that your `smetki` class is taken from a database. It contains a foreign key to another class (`trosoci`). Now when you loaded the `smetki` from the database, it did lazy loading, meaning it knows that there is supposed to be a `trosoci`, but didn't load its data.

Now when you tried to access any properties of this `trosoci` in your view, it needs to load the `trosoci` object from the database before having access to the property in question. Since the context to the database has been closed already, it cannot load the data in question and throws the given exception.

Possible solutions:

a) change lazy loading to eager loading (globally or specifically for `trosoci` with `dc.smetkis.Fetch(customer).OrderBy(a => a.smID).ToList();` or whatever the correct command for your ORM my be)

b) map all contents you'll need into a model, while your context (the using) is still open, so that your code can ask the database again for missing data

c) make a dummy serialization (with `JavaScriptSerializer`) of the objects, which will access all fields and thus load them from the database.